# problem with grand totals

Tags: javascript

here is the code that i am using for the sub totals and grand totals but it gives me a strange result. pl. help

```
function totalprice()
{
    len = document.forms["form1"]["quantity[]"].length;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        a = document.forms["form1"]["quantity[]"][i].value;
        b = document.forms["form1"]["price[]"][i].value
        c = a * b

        document.forms["form1"]["total[]"][i].value = c;
        sum = 0;
        for (b=0;b<len;b++){
            var d = document.forms["form1"]["total[]"][b].value;
            var sum = sum + d;
            document.forms["form1"]["grandtotal"].value = sum;
        }    
    }
}
```

and here is the html code

```
<form action="here.php" method="post" name="form1">
Quantity: <input name="quantity[]" size="10">Price: <input name="price[]" size="10" onblur="totalprice();">
Total: <input name="total[]" size="10" readonly=true><br>

Quantity: <input name="quantity[]" size="10">Price: <input name="price[]" size="10" onblur="totalprice();">
Total: <input name="total[]" size="10" readonly=true><br>

Quantity: <input name="quantity[]" size="10">Price: <input name="price[]" size="10" onblur="totalprice();">
Total: <input name="total[]" size="10" readonly=true><br>

Grand Total: <input name="grandtotal">


<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What message do you get?

Comment: You should simplify this to the simplest possible program that still exhibits "strange" behavior, indent it properly, and then post it here along with an explanation of what the expected behavior is and what the actual behavior is.  This question contains too little information and probably too much code.

Comment: Your grandtotal input doesn't have a type.

Comment: @David and @ Zippy
i am sorry. finally found a solution.
following code worked. thanks all.
function totalprice()
{
 len = document.forms["form1"]["quantity[]"].length;
 
 for(i=0;i<len;i++){
a = document.forms["form1"]["quantity[]"][i].value;
b = document.forms["form1"]["price[]"][i].value
 
c = a * b
 
document.forms["form1"]["total[]"][i].value = c;
 sum = 0;
 for (b=0;b<len;b++){
  var d = Number(document.forms["form1"]["total[]"][b].value);
  var sum = Number(sum + d);
  document.forms["form1"]["grandtotal"].value = sum;
 }
 
}

}

Comment: the code you posted in your comment is really hard to read - could you please edit your question and add the solution to the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still looks like the "grand total" loop is inside the "total" loop, so you're calculating the grand total multiple times.